# Show bound byte array as an image in DataListView

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I'm using the `ObjectListView` controls set, specifically the `DataListView`. Here is my code.

`Datasource` of the control:

```
dataListView1.DataSource = this.ViewModel.DataSet;
```

where `DataSet` is populated by:

```
this.ViewModel.DataSet = HSGlobals.ctx.Entities<Product>().All()
                        .Where(p => productIdList.Contains(p.Id)).Select(p => new
                        {
                            Nazwa = p.Name,
                            Kod = p.Code,
                            Dostępność = p.AvaibleQuantity,
                            Typ = p.ProductType.Name,
                            Miara = p.MeasureUnit.Name,
                            Grafika = p.ProductImage.Image
                        }).ToList();
```

`Grafika` is a byte array - an image obtained from database.

When `dataListView` is displayed, the `Grafika` column shows only type of this field - `System.byte[]`.

**What I have to do to display just an image?**

I've already tried `ImageGetter` and `Renderer` properties but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial approach should work, if you attach an instance of the `BrightIdeasSoftware.ImageRenderer` to the Renderer of the column.

For the ImageRenderer, the image can be sourced from:

- a byte-array (normally when the image to be shown is stored as a value in a database)
- an int, which is treated as an index into the image list
- a string, which is treated first as a file name, and failing that as an index into the image list
- an ICollection of ints or strings, which will be drawn as consecutive images

Assuming your byte-stream contains valid data to create a Bitmap this should do.

EDIT: Also make sure that the `OwnerDraw` property of the OLV is set to `true`, IIRC this is a requirement that custom images will be drawn.

Comment: I missed this OwnerDraw property. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your byte array is a valid image,
Use a memorystream to consume your byte array, then construct a Bitmap:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(yourImageByteArray);
var image = new Bitmap(ms)
```

Then bind your image to the DataList.

### Edit

To add to the objectviewlists imagelist you need to do:

```
this.listView.LargeImageList.Images.Add(yourImages);
```

Comment: You need to make sure you ImageUrl is bound correctly. refer to this url: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1399196

Comment: What ImageUrl? See my tags, this is WinForms. I'm using this control - [link](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)

Comment: Can you describe it more clearly? I dont't know well this control. I'm binding list of class objects to my dataListView, one of class fields is an image. This need to be done separately? Images in another binding? or what?